# Power BI: Min/Max values on line chart without second instance on Values tab

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, ms-office

What I am trying to solve is to show Min and Max values (PS190 bar) "as is" in Line chart, without putting Second instance for Min or Max in Values field. I just confirmation and idea, does it has to be like that I need always instances in values for showing or is there any other way (like in Excel) where the data is read as it is (original data)?

It wouldnt bother me a lot, but I am having different parameteres that also have to be included, and that would be A LOOOT instances in values field, what I dont wanna - especially for my colleagues that are not experienced in PBI. But one of them asked me exactly the same: "why such a powerful tool hasnt this simple thing as in Excel?!"...I was thinking I can do it, but only with additional instances!!

Help appreciated!!!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but it looks like you are just looking for the data labels to be added. You can do this by selecting the format pane and turn data labels on. If this is not what you are looking for kindly explain in further detail. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wanna have min/max values using one instance in the Values field. But I can have either one for MIN, or MAX, AVG or SUM...and thats not what I wanted. I have to add as many instances of PS190 as I wanted to show - is there a way to show both MIN and MAX on the same Line chart?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that's possible.